# Is it possible to enable ClearType on Visual Studio only?

Tags: visual-studio, cleartype

I really like how Consolas looks with ClearType enabled but unfortunately it makes everything else look terrible. Is there any way to enable this on a per app basis? I noticed that putty (the terminal emulator) has options for ClearType separate from the display setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have an application that enables or disables ClearType independently of the system-wide setting... but it requires that the application be specifically written to do it, since it involves passing specific parameters to the Windows API when you're creating fonts. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, VS wasn't written to do this. (And, incidentally, I don't think .NET supports it either, without resorting to P/Invoke.)

Comment: Sounds like what I was thinking..oh well

Answer (score 2):

Getting bad results with ClearType but good looking Consolas is pretty strange.  Try out the [ClearType tuner.](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypePowerToy.mspx)